# Colorbox (lightbox plug-in) limiting number of photos in array

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I implemented the Colorbox plug-in on one of my clients' sites recently, and it's limiting the number of photos it loads into the lightbox to five. Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Load the page
2. Click one of the large images (not thumbnails) to load it into the lightbox
3. Click through the Previous/Next navigation or click the lightbox image to advance
4. The image set loops at five when it should display nine

[Example page 1](http://amatoarchitecture.com/new/brooklyn.html)

[Example page 2](http://amatoarchitecture.com/new/oakvale.html)

On each page, there are greater than five photos in the set. I can click on large photo #6 or greater, and it loads the image, but there is no navigation and no "Photo X of X" numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the class you are triggering the colorbox on has only 5 images 'group1'. See my screenshot. Each div there has the 'group1' class inside. Could you add additional divs with images to the '.rsContainer' I have listed in the screenshot?

[image]

Comment: In the page source code, there are 9 <div class="group1 cboxElement"> within the <div class="royalSlider rsDefault">. I can see that in the live code's source, there are only 5. AFAIK, there is nothing missing from my page source code, and also the divs you're mentioning are dynamically generated.

Perhaps it's a RoyalSlider setting that I need to investigate.

Comment: Yes could be a RoyalSlider issue, If you create a fiddle with your original HTML, js, it would be easier to investigate further.

Comment: I created a fiddle with everything in there. The site functions as normal, except now the Colorbox isn't firing at all.
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/twohats/034oq1g5/4/)

Comment: Looks like fiddle doesnt like it when external resources aren't loaded over https.

Comment: I removed all the external resources and loaded the contents as internal resources. Looks like everything is firing correctly. Still experiencing the same problem. [Amato Architecture Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twohats/034oq1g5/8/)

Comment: Also, in case it's not obvious, you have to click Projects >> Oakvale or Projects >> Brooklyn to get to the example code.

Comment: Maybe it'd work if there's just the 'http://amatoarchitecture.com/new/brooklyn.html' page in the fiddle.

Comment: That's actually what I did. I think the JS code driving the side accordion menu is what makes it need another click.

Comment: At this point I think I would suggest looking into trying a different lightbox plugin. You may try http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ "Magnific Popup". If that doesnt work you could try changing your slider plugin, possibly https://amazingslider.com "Amazing Slider"